# Searching in excel sheet using java basic script

Tags: java, excel

I am not sure how to go about with the task. so i'll just elaborate the things i need/want in this scenario..

1. I want to search a record in the excel sheet based on some criteria( 4 criteria specified)
2. so based on it i may find 4 to 5 records matching the criteria. I want to display these records row by row in the search window itself ( like adding a excel object if i'm not wrong)
3. Then when i click a particular record from the search result in the search window, the complete details of tat record should be displayed in the main screen (i.e it should retrieve the entire record from excel sheet into the GUI console.)

This is the task. Any idea how to do it? If the excel rows can be added as excel object, then how do i do it? any tutorials..suggestion would be very helpful.

By the way iam using java swing and excel sheet as backend.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) is a popular framework for working with Office files (word, excel, powerpoint). Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

In order to read Excel documents in Java, I suggest you use a third-party library like [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/).

You will have to read the records from the Excel and probably create instances of your own model for these records. Build some model logic for searching based on the criteria. Put the ones matching the criteria into a `JTable` model.

Handle mouse events or selection events in the table and use your model again to located the selected record and display the full record where you have to.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need some lib to read and search Excel files on the fly in Java.

I recommend using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html).

Have a look at the [Quick Guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) and [Getting the cell contents](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents).